# STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT in xcode problem

Tags: xcode, firefox, plugins, npapi

have folowing code:

```
NPVariant type;
STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT("click", type);
```

and the xcode returns

"error: expected expression before 'uint32_t'"

anyone can give me a hand with this?

Comment: if you haven't already, you may consider using FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org) instead of writing NPAPI directly; there are very few cases on the desktop where FireBreath isn't a better solution than doing it yourself, particularly since it already has tested and stable workarounds for a lot of different browser problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this as well.  Based on this bug i found in the npapi project, i solved the problem by not using the macro, and using what it expands to instead, then applying what the patch shows.
http://code.google.com/p/npapi-headers/issues/detail?id=3

-    NPString str = { _val, uint32_t(strlen(_val)) };

+    NPString str = { _val, (uint32_t)(strlen(_val)) };

Basically, wrap uint32_t in parenthesis, then gcc will compile it.

So the full replacement for the macro is

```
NPVariant type;
type.type = NPVariantType_String;
NPString str = { "click", (uint32_t)(strlen("click")) };
type.value.stringValue = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check [what this macro resolves into](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/base/npruntime.h#167) you get:

```
NPVariant type;
type.type = NPVariantType_String;
NPString str = { "click", uint32_t(strlen("click")) };
type.value.stringValue = str;
```

At least this way one can understand what the error message refers to. I'm still not sure what the reason for the error is however - maybe your Xcode or gcc version is outdated. According to [the documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mac%3aBuild_Requirements#Compatibility_Matrix) you need at least Xcode 2.5 and gcc 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

in your npruntime.h find these two MACRO

```
#define STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(_val, _v)                                        \
NP_BEGIN_MACRO                                                                \
    (_v).type = NPVariantType_String;                                         \
    NPString str = { _val, **(uint32_t)** strlen(_val) };                          \
    (_v).value.stringValue = str;                                             \
NP_END_MACRO

#define STRINGN_TO_NPVARIANT(_val, _len, _v)                                  \
NP_BEGIN_MACRO                                                                \
    (_v).type = NPVariantType_String;                                         \
    NPString str = { _val, **(uint32_t)**_len };                                  \
    (_v).value.stringValue = str;                                             \
NP_END_MACRO
```

add (uint32_t) cast before strlen(_val) and _len